# Why doesn't starting websphere application server require admin credentials?

Tags: security, administrator, reboot, credentials, websphere

We use following syntax to stop a webpshere application server:

`stopServer.sh servername -user admin_userid -password admin_password`

However the start command is less luminous

`startServer.sh servername`

Why does only stop command requires admin credentials while start command does not ask for any?

Answer (score 3):

stopServer.sh and startServer.sh have and should have the same privilege/restriction. Maybe the server Admin had restriction the stopServer.sh to admin users only.

But I'm pretty sure that isn't the case in the default installation.

*EDIT*

I recheck, here the new info:

The [startServer](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.soafep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_startserver.html&resultof=%22startServer%22%20%22startserv%22%20) doesn't need user/pass even if security is enable

The [stopServer](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_stopserver.html&resultof=%22stopServer%22%20%22stopserv%22%20) need username and password credential if security is enable.

IMHO, they design the server this way, because there's more consequences when you stop a server than when you start it.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense. But that is the default behavior. Up on creation of a WAS profile, if you provide admin credentials, that is required only while shutting down the profile server not while starting it.

Comment: oh you're right, I changed my answer with new info. I'm used to use websphere commerce, and apparently it's not the same things about credential